# Getting the value of <tr> in a <td> on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Lets say I have a table

```
<table id="data-table" id="test">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>value1</th>
            <th>value2</th>
            <th>value3</th>
            <th>value4</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td id="class1"><%= value.valueOne() %></td>
            <td id="class2"><%= value.valueTwo() %></td>
            <td id="class3"><%= value.valueThree() %></td>
            <td id="class4"><%= value.valueFour() %></td>
        </tr>
        <%
        }
        %>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

How can I get the `<td>` values of a `<tr>`  as seperate variables when a particular `<tr>` is clicked ?  I tried using the following code snippet but it does not help

```
$(this).closest('td').closest('tr').html()
```

Comment: what do you mean by value of `tr` in `td`? value of `tr == its td`right?

Comment: Post the rendered HTML and the JQ you're using to call the code you posted.

Comment: what is this " <%
        }
        %>", between the closing </tr> and </tbody>

Answer (score 2):

I think you're saying that you want to get each of the values of the `td` elements in whatever `tr` was clicked.

You can do this with `find`, `map` and `get` to get an array of values:

```
$('#test tbody tr').click(function() {
    var values = $(this).find('td').map(function() {
        return $(this).text();
    }).get();
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lonesomeday/sfNE8/1/) (NB that I have removed one of the `id` values on your `table` element: you can't have two...)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method to delegate the click event on `tr` to the `#data-table`.

Then, you can use `$(this).find('td')` to get all the td elements inside the current clicked element and map their inner contents to an array.

```
$('#data-table').on('click', 'tr', function() {
    var values = $(this).find('td').map(function() {
        return $(this).text();
    });

    alert(values[0]); // first td
    alert(values[1]); // second td
    alert(values[2]); // third td
    alert(values[3]); // fourth td
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cPpzY/

You can also store your cells in different variables, supposing you want to pick just the first two cells for example:

```
$('#data-table').on('click', 'tr', function() {
    var first = $(this).find('td:eq(0)').text();
    var second = $(this).find('td:eq(1)').text();

    alert(first);
    alert(second);
});
```

In this case, we are using the [`:eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) selector to pick an element at a specific index.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cPpzY/1/

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using a templating engine to generate a list of `tr` elements, in that case you need to use `class` attribute instead of `id` as id of an element must be unique

```
        <td class="class1"><%= value.valueOne() %></td>
        <td class="class2"><%= value.valueTwo() %></td>
        <td class="class3"><%= value.valueThree() %></td>
        <td class="class4"><%= value.valueFour() %></td>
```

then on row click

```
$('tr').click(function(){
    var v1 = $(this).find('.class1').text();
    var v2 = $(this).find('.class2').text();
    var v3 = $(this).find('.class3').text();
    var v4 = $(this).find('.class4').text();
})
```